# Why doesn't WebStorm extract JavaScript files from TypeScript files?

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I use WebStorm to write Angular 4 project. I see that although I create TypeScript files and my application works fine, I don't see any JavaScript files in the project. WebStorm usually "translate" TypeScript files to JavaScript files. I don't know why it's not happening here.

Here is my settings for TypeScript:

[image]

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

If I look at the filesystem of the project, I see this:

[image]

There is no triangle next to .ts files.

However, I can see that `dist` folder includes some js files. Maybe it's a feature of Angular 4. It packs all TypeScript files and generates one bundled js file.

Comment: If your "application works fine" then you must have the js files in place. Webstorm will usually group together the different types of files of the same original ts file together so you'll have an entry for "index.ts" with a triangle icon on the left side. Clicking that will show you the js file and js.map file (if genererated).

Answer (score 1):

In your `tsconfig.json`, you have `"compileOnSave": false`. If this option is not enabled, `.js` files are not emitted by the built-in compiler, it's only used as a service (for error reporting, etc.). Your application is likely build by `ng serve` that uses webpack to compile and bundle your files, so you don't need your `.js` files being generated using the built-in compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It translates the TS files only when you enable it. The question is why would you want to have translated JS files in your `/src`? The angular app builds automatically with build tool you use.

For example with Angular CLI tool, you can build by running `ng build` or when developing app you can build, watch files and serve with `ng serve`

To answer the original question, this blog post should help you https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/03/how-to-compile-typescript-in-webstorm/